# NestJS Typeorm: Run insert operation with multiple repositories

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have couple of APIs running CRUD operations, for instance:

```
POST /table
POST /chair
```

and each have their own repository instance in their respective Service file. Below is sample code for Table's service file -

`table.service.ts`

```
// import statements

export class TableService {
  private readonly tableRepository: Repository<TableEntity>;
    constructor(
      @Inject('CONNECTION') private connection: DataSource,
    ) {
      this.tableRepository = connection.getRepository(TableEntity);
    }

  async create(createTableDto: CreateTable) {
    const result = await this.tableRepository.insert({...createTableDto});
    return this.tableRepository.findOneOrFail({where: {id: result.identifiers[0].id}});
  }
}
```

Service file for Chair has similar implementation.

I have another api, lets call it /test, which would perform insert operation on `TableEntity` and `ChairEntity` by calling the `create` method from their service file -

`test.service.ts`

```
export class TestService {
  constructor(
    private readonly tableService: TableService,
    private readonly chairService: ChairService,
    @Inject('CONNECTION') private connection: DataSource,
  ) {}

  async create() {
   const tableData = ...;
   const chairData = ...;
   tableService.create(tableData);
   chairService.create(chairData); 
  }
```

How would I run the above operation in transaction? I cannot use [DataSource.transaction](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactions) because all database operations must be executed using provided entity manager, which is not the case for me.

Can I leverage `connection` object? Or do we have any other approach?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the most recent version of nestjs 9 and typeOrm 0.3.11 here is how I accomplished this:

```
import { HttpException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository, InjectDataSource } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Like, Repository, DataSource, EntityManager  } from 'typeorm';
import { Users } from './entities/users.entity';
import { UsersRoles } from './entities/users_roles.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Users)
        private usersRepository: Repository<Users>,
        @InjectRepository(UsersRoles)
        private usersRolesRepository: Repository<UsersRoles>,
        @InjectDataSource()
        private dataSource: DataSource,
) {}

async createUser(data: any, submit_user: any): Promise<any> {
    try {
        const result = await this.dataSource.manager.transaction(async (entityManager: EntityManager) => {
            const user = new Users();
            user.name = data.name;
            user.email = data.email;
            user.created_at = new Date();
            user.updated_at = new Date();
            await entityManager.save(user);

            const userRole = new UsersRoles();
            userRole.users_id = user.id;
            userRole.roles_id = data.role_id;
            userRole.supervisor_id = data.supervisor_id || null;
            userRole.submitted_by = submit_user.id;
            userRole.created_at = new Date();
            userRole.updated_at = new Date();
            await entityManager.save(userRole);
        });
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new HttpException(error, 500);
    }
   }
}
```

To explain it essentially you are injecting the datasource from TypeORM and using that with the transaction manager you create a callback function with the entityManager parameter that you'll use inside.

You instantiate the 2 entities in my case User and User roles and add the data you want to save then execute the save with that entityManager param.

Since you are using the transaction manager it should handle rollbacks for you if it fails but would need to test to 100% verify that.